Under which conditions does PCA consistently estimate latent factors in a Dynamic Factor Model?
Consider a dataset of N time series and T observation periods.
Assume each series $x_t$ is generated from a single (unobserved) common factor $f_t$ following this model:
$$
X_t = \Lambda f_t + \epsilon_t, \quad \text{with} \quad \epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon) \\
f_t = \rho f_{t-1} + v_t, \quad \text{with} \quad v_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_v)  \quad and \quad |\rho|<1
$$
where $X_t$ is a $N \times 1$ column vector of observations, $\Lambda$ is a $N \times 1$ vector of "factor loadings" indicating how the common factor influences each observed series and $\epsilon_t$ is $N \times 1$ vector of gaussian innovation terms with no serial or cross-sectional correlation.
The common factor $f_t$ follows an AR(1) dynamic and in both equations the idiosyncratic terms, $\epsilon_t$ and $v_t$, have finite variance.
This should be a very simple dynamic factor model setup.
Under which conditions the first Principal Component of the observation matrix should estimate consistently the common factor?
I am interested in testing the performance of different factor extraction methods within small samples and I have built a Monte Carlo simulation for this purpose. However, I am observing that as the cross-section (N) of my (artificial) dataset increases, the estimates of the common factor deteriorates in terms of higher Mean Squared Error (MSE) between the estimated factor series and the true one. I'd like to know why.
On the contrary, I do observe that as T increases the estimates become more precise, with a lower MSE.
To obtain the artificial dataset I first generate an AR(1) series with gaussian error terms to play the role of the common factor $f_t$. Then, I draw randomly N factor loadings to compute N linear transformations of the original latent series contaminated with other gaussian error terms. Such that, e.g., the first observed series is obtained as:
$$
x_{1,t} = \lambda_1 f_t + \epsilon_{1,t}
$$
Thank you very much in advance for your replies!
